# jQuery: data processing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm using jQuery UI and dataTables.
Uploading data via ajax to a table. In this data i have a checkboxes. So they should be treated accordingly ($('.checkbox_class').uniform())
The problem is that the table has the paging and processed only the first 10 lines, while the rest still remain. How to handle the following items? I wanted to use the live(), but there's no suitable type of event.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables have their own set of events built in, so you can use that `draw` event:
(Also `.live()` is deprecated so use `.on()` instead)

```
$("#myTable").on("draw", function() {
    myFunctionToReapplyClasses();
});
```

That will fire the function every time you change the page or filter the results.